# GetLogicalDriveStrings() and char - Where am I doing wrongly

Tags: c++, char, msdn, const-char

I want to search a file which may be present in any drives such as C:\, D:\ etc. Using `GetLogicalDriveStrings` I can able to get the list of drives but when I add anything extra for the output, I am getting a `null` in the output prompt. Here is my code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

// Buffer length
DWORD mydrives = 100;
// Buffer for drive string storage
char lpBuffer[100];
const char *extFile = "text.ext";

// You may want to try the wmain() version
int main(void)
{
    DWORD test;
    int i;
    test = GetLogicalDriveStrings(mydrives, (LPWSTR)lpBuffer);
    if(test != 0)
    {
        printf("GetLogicalDriveStrings() return value: %d, Error (if any): %d \n", test, GetLastError());
        printf("The logical drives of this machine are:\n");
        // Check up to 100 drives...
        for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
        printf("%c%s", lpBuffer[i],extFile);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
        printf("GetLogicalDriveStrings() is failed lor!!! Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I want above output as `C:\text.ext D:\text.ext ...` rather I am getting `text.ext` only. I am using `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express`

Comment: You're assigning "text.ext" to `extFile` 100 times, and then printing a string consisting of `lpBuffer[100]` (which is past the end of the buffer) and something called `datFile` which doesn't appear anywhere else in your example. Please check your code more carefully before posting for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`GetLogicalDriveStrings()` returns a double-null terminated list of null-terminated strings. E.g., say you had drives A, B and C in your machine. The returned string would look like this:

`A:\<nul>B:\<nul>C:\<nul><nul>`

You can use the following code to iterate through the strings in the returned buffer and print each one in turn:

```
DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
char szLogicalDrives[MAX_PATH] = {0};
DWORD dwResult = GetLogicalDriveStrings(dwSize,szLogicalDrives);

if (dwResult > 0 && dwResult <= MAX_PATH)
{
    char* szSingleDrive = szLogicalDrives;
    while(*szSingleDrive)
    {
        printf("Drive: %s\n", szSingleDrive);

        // get the next drive
        szSingleDrive += strlen(szSingleDrive) + 1;
    }
}
```

Note that the details of how the function works, including the example code that I shamelessly copied and pasted, can be found by [**reading the docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmm.. thanks :) Just to properly run, set in Project Properties Unicode to Not Set

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to put the printf in the loop?

Currently, you set extFile 100 times (just to be sure?!)

```
   for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
       extFile = "text.ext";
```

You meant to show all the drive letters in a loop:

```
   for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
   {
        extFile = "text.ext";
        printf("%c%s", lpBuffer[i], extFile); //I guess you mean extFile here?
   }
```

Comment: Well, yes I want the output as `C:\text.ext ... upto nth drive:\text.ext`. I've modified my code a little bit please check...

Comment: See Jonathan's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
WCHAR szLogicalDrives[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
DWORD dwResult = GetLogicalDriveStrings(dwSize, szLogicalDrives);

CStringArray m_Drives;
m_Drives.RemoveAll();

if (dwResult > 0 && dwResult <= MAX_PATH)
{
    WCHAR* szSingleDrive = szLogicalDrives;
    while (*szSingleDrive)
    {
        UINT nDriveType = GetDriveType(szSingleDrive);
        m_Drives.Add(CString(szSingleDrive, 2));

        // get the next drive
        szSingleDrive += wcslen(szSingleDrive) + 1;
    }
}
return m_Drives;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DriveList {
    protected:

    LPTSTR m_driveList;
    DWORD m_driveCount;
    DWORD m_bufSize = 32 * sizeof(TCHAR);

    public:

    virtual ~DriveList() {
        free(m_driveList);
    }

    DriveList() {
        m_driveList = (LPTSTR)malloc(m_bufSize);
    }

    int getDriveCount() const {
        return m_driveCount;
    }

    TCHAR operator[] (const int index) const {
        return m_driveList[index];
    }

    void loadDriveList() {
        DWORD mask;
        if((mask = GetLogicalDrives()) == 0) {
            throw;
        }

        m_driveCount = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x <= 25; x++ ) {
            if(mask & 1) {
                m_driveList[m_driveCount] = TCHAR(65 + x);
                m_driveCount += 1;
            }
            mask >>= 1; 
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)