# How to specify the directory for searching file all over the system

Tags: c++, windows

I am writing a file system program in C++. Now I try to write a file finding function. First I want program be able to search the file in all system. I use FindFirstFile and FindNextFile Windows API functions. First I should call FindFirstFile , and give it the directory, where it must search the file. But I don't know, how to specify the diirectory so that FindFirstFile searches in all the system.
Please, help me with that question. I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what I've found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx):

> you cannot use a trailing backslash () in the lpFileName input string
>   for FindFirstFile, therefore it may not be obvious how to search root
>   directories. If you want to see files or get the attributes of a root
>   directory, the following options would apply: To examine files in a
>   root directory, you can use `"C:\*"` and step through the directory by
>   using FindNextFile. To get the attributes of a root directory, use the
>   GetFileAttributes function. Note  Prepending the string "\?\" does
>   not allow access to the root directory.

to get a list of available drives you might use `GetLogicalDriveStrings()`. This returns a double-null terminated list of null-terminated strings. E.g., say you had drives `A, B` and `C` in your machine. The returned string would look like this:

```
A:\<nul>B:\<nul>C:\<nul><nul>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18573199/1141471

Comment: Thank you for the answer, computer. Let me ask you a question. As I understand, "C:\" is a root directory of computer in Windows system ? Am I right?

Comment: yes. Unix abstracts the nature of this tree hierarchy entirely and in Unix and Unix-like systems the root directory is denoted by / sign. Though the root directory is conventionally referred to as /, the directory entry itself has no name—its name is the "empty" part before the initial directory separator character (/). All filesystem entries, including mounted filesystems are "branches" of this root.

Comment: Under DOS, OS/2, and Microsoft Windows, each partition has a drive letter assignment (labeled C:\ for a particular partition C) and there is no common root directory above that. DOS, OS/2, and Windows do support more abstract hierarchies, with partitions mountable within a directory of another drive, though this is rarely seen. from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory

Comment: is this enough for you to solve your problem or do you have some additional questions?

Comment: To say truth, I have some questions, and have to take your time some more. :) . So , in Windows there is no common directory. But how Windows search file in MyComputer when you go to Start->search ?

Comment: we don't know what it's developers implemented, but for example we see that it can be done the way I answered below: listing all drives and iterating with FindFirstFile then

Comment: O, now I understand You. Thank you very much for! You really help me!