# How to access hidden partitions/volumes

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, wmi, disk-partitioning

I have to write a code to access hidden disk partitions/volumes using c# or c++.
But could not find any help reference on the matter.

As a hidden volume, it does not contain a "Disk Letter", so you can´t just type "C:\" and access it.
A example would be the "recovery partition" that comes with Windows. You can´t see it on explorer but it is there.

My application will write and read data from thoose partitions and I have to find a way of doing something like "c:\" for thoose.

[image: Volumes 5,6 are hidden partitions]

In the above image, volumes 5 and 6 are hidden partitions.
I have found this link on stackoverflow but it only "list" de partitions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc542456(v=VS.85).aspx

**EDIT**

The problem is: even using WMI as suguested I could´t find how to filter the the Volume when looking for files.
Example, `select * from win32_DataFile` will list all Files in the machine.

I think should be a way of filtering the Volumes using their ID(or name).
Something like:

```
select * from win32_DataFile 
where volumeId = '\\?\Volume{2d5f3a68-75f5-44c4-aa42-716b45811916}\'
```

Or a more beautiful way like:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\?\Volume{6ff7748e-78db-4838-8896-254b074918f5}\");
```

Also, I found a excelent awenser in about Partitions and Volumes (their are not the same thing)
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7b2ddd6-f245-49ed-8fec-3b6e08e75369/how-do-i-find-the-partition-guid?forum=winservergen

**EDIT2**

As awensered by Harry, using "\.\Volume...." was a good way to recovery files. But I could not find a way to write(create) a new file using c#. 
The best approch so far is using pinvoke to c++ CreateFile method/handle.

---

Any advice?

Comment: "could not find any help reference on the matter" - isn't link you have in a question give you plenty of hints for next searches? Did you read details about each function used in sample? At this point your question is likely very broad for SO...

Comment: In C++ you can use `GetLogicalDriveStrings` http://stackoverflow.com/a/18573199/4603670 and `GetDriveType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FindFirstVolume() API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364425(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a path to the root of each volume on the system.

For example, this code prints the path to the first volume, and the name of the first file in the root directory of that volume:

```
    HANDLE h1, h2;
    wchar_t volpath[4096];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA find_data;

    h1 = FindFirstVolume(volpath, _countof(volpath));

    printf("%ws\n", volpath);

    wcscat_s(volpath, _countof(volpath), L"*.*");

    h2 = FindFirstFile(volpath, &find_data);

    printf("%ws\n", find_data.cFileName);
```

(In production code, you would need to add error checking, etc.)

**Addendum**

FindFirstVolume returns a path like this: `\\?\Volume{6ff7748e-78db-4838-8896-254b074918f5}\`

If you're using the Win32 API (CreateFile, etc.) in C++ you can use that path directly, but due to a bug or limitation in .NET it doesn't work with file management classes such as Directory.GetFiles().  (You could P/Invoke to the Win32 API, of course, but that's awkward.)

Instead, you can work around the problem by replacing the question mark that appears at the beginning of the path with a dot:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\.\Volume{6ff7748e-78db-4838-8896-254b074918f5}\");
```

Comment: Harry, many thanks for the tip of using "\\.\" that works fine for GetFiles. About writing files, thats something more deep i guess. I tried using File.Create and other Stream low level methods, but keep getting this exception: "FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of "\\.\" in the path." I guess the only way will be using pinvoke to the CreateFile c++ methods.

Comment: Drat.  Would it be acceptable for your program to temporarily mount the volume(s) on a folder somewhere?  Or if you have admin privilege you could create a directory symbolic link, that would be a less intrusive approach.

Comment: I don´t think that would be a good way to my application. Any way your awenser helped a lot. I will problably use pinvoke for some situations and might re-write c# File class to support this kind of operatitions in the future. Btw thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If your program is Windows specific you can work with WMI. I worked a lot with WMI and it is very Handy to do any Kind of Manipulation or getting data about Windows Systems.

First of all you can download the wmiexplorer to see the available data and classes. the relevant Namespace for you will be `root\cimv`. There you can find various interesting classes for you:

- [Win32_LogicalDisk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx): Contains all disks, also hidden ones.
- [CIM_Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387248(v=vs.85).aspx): Contains all directories (As far as I know also from hidden Disks)
- [CIM_DataFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387236(v=vs.85).aspx): Contains all files (I also think this one contains also the files from hidden disks)
- There are many more classes you can use e.g. to retrieve file permissions... Microsoft has a pretty good [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792179(v=vs.85).aspx) about it

Next, you can implement your desired WMI queries into your C# (or VB.NET) program. For example, this one will print all disks:

```
WqlObjectQuery wqlQuery = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wqlQuery);

foreach (ManagementObject disk in searcher.Get()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(disk.ToString());
}
```

As you can seen, WMI supports queries like SQL (although it's not as powerful...)

WMI also supports methots for most of ist classes. For example you can check each disk for Errors:

```
foreach (ManagementObject disk in searcher.Get()) 
{
    if(shouldCheckThisDisk)
        disk.Chkdsk();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Thomas. I managed to use WMI querys to retrive pettry usefull info. But could not find a way to list "all files of Drive". Because WHEN the drive is hidden the "Driver" property is null or empty. I can´t just find a way to filter that info, and withought the Path filter it brings all files of your entire machine, hehe. Any way thanks a lot